# How to continue the foreach in try and catch?

Tags: c#, .net

If I catch an exception during execution of a foreach, can I continue execution?

```
foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                //do something
            }
            //do something
        }
        catch
        {
           // If there is an error in the foreach, I want it to keep on going
        }
    }
```

I am asking this because it suddenly terminates before the `foreach` gets all the files.

Answer (score 10):

Simply do:

```
foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            try
            {
                //do some thing
            }
            catch
            {
               // If there is an error on the foreach, I want it to keep on going to search another one
            }
        }
        //do some thing
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) {
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path)) {
        try {
            //do some thing
        } catch { /* log an error */ }
    }

    try {
        //do some thing
    } catch { /* log an error */ }
}
```

Comment: on the /* log an error */ in each of the catch, i want it to keep on going, so if I put return; , will it terminate?

Comment: Yes, it will.  You don't want to return from the catch blocks, just log an error and do nothing else.

Comment: @user1726086 if you use a `return` statement, it will exit the surrounding method. You can continue doing stuff as long as you're not `returning` or `throw`-ing or `break`-ing or any action that ends the loop or exits the method.

Comment: @birryree Method, technically.  C# doesn't have functions.  :)

Comment: @cdhowie Corrected - C terminology creep. :)

Comment: Yes.  That's what you've been told by two people now.  Have you even tried the code?

Comment: I avoid using the return in the catch by using an "echo"  command or  resort to  doing "Logging" instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            //do something
        }
        //do something
    }
    catch(Excepion)
    {
       // If there is an error in the foreach, log error and...
            continue;
    }
}
```